# I can't get Youtube API to work in Squarespace

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, squarespace

I'm trying to control a youtube iframe in my squarespace website. I want it to autoplay when the page loads and then if I scroll and it's not in the viewport anymore, I want it to pause.

Here is what I did:

This is my iframe:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uuRC8Pmud3o?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And this is my script:

```
<script>
  // This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.  
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // This function YouTube player
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }  

  // The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      done = true;
    }
    // Loop the video
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      player.playVideo(); 
    }
  }

  // On scroll Pause/Play the video player
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var top_of_element = $("#ytplayer").offset().top;
    var bottom_of_element = $("#ytplayer").offset().top + $("#ytplayer").outerHeight();
    var bottom_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();

    if((bottom_of_screen > top_of_element) && (top_of_screen < bottom_of_element)){
      // The element is visible, trigger play click event
      player.playVideo()
    }
    else {
      // The element is not visible, trigger pause click event
      player.pauseVideo()
    }
  });

</script>
```

I tried adding the script to squarespace using many ways but it's not working. Where has the script to be injected?

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Youtube IFRAME API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#IFrame_Player_API), just add `autoplay=1` at the end of your URL like:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I think this is also confirmed in the [squarespace forum](https://answers.squarespace.com/questions/8403/how-can-i-autoplay-a-video.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have just figured this out.

Squarespace creates it's own players and also it dynamically creates iframes so it's a bit complicated. Also getting player using DOM element doesn't seems to work and all iframe elements have the same id = "player" so that adds up to the problem.

The code below is what I have come to literally 5min ago. 
Just copy/paste to the header code injection in the Squarespace config.

What it does is it acquire all the original YouTube API players as soon as possible and pause playback to avoid horrible lag when my old GPU tries to video-decode all those video instances. Then I have a code which plays the video when it appears on the screen and pauses videos that are not visible anymore. Now it plays smoothly and I can add even more videos. In my case you can see one full-screen video at a time as you scroll down. I have 7x 720p videos stacked up. It looks cool, but I found out that my GPU is lagging badly when more than 5 videos were used, initially I was thinking that it's a network speed problem but my task manager showed 100% on GPU video-encoding. So far worked on Firefox and Chrome.

I have just managed to make this work so there is a lot of testing and tweaking to be done.

USE ON YOUR OWN RISK ! :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Prepare YouTube iframe API ..
// this is probably redundant, but works fine

var tag = document.createElement ('script');

tag.id  = 'iframe-api';
tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';

var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName ('script')[0];

firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore (tag, firstScriptTag);

// When Iframe is ready ..

var iframes = [];
var players = [];

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady () {

    // console.log ("onYouTubeIframeAPIReady");

    var player_containers = document.querySelectorAll (".sqs-video-background.content-fill");

    for (var i = 0; i < player_containers.length; i ++) {

        player_containers [i].addEventListener ("DOMNodeInserted", function (e) {

            var node = e.target;

            if (node.tagName.toUpperCase () === "IFRAME") {

                // console.log ("PLAYER : " + node.id + " TAG : " + node.tagName);

                iframes.push (node);

                // unfortunately it seems that we cannot catch the player creation event so 
                // the actual players are probably created after this code
                // by calling this function we can catch previous players early on 
                // except the last one

                initPlayers ();
            }

        }, false);
    }
}

function initPlayers () {

    // they have all the same id (!!!)

    // however it seems it picks the last created one so not the same one over and over
    // I didn't touched this, it works so far

    var player = YT.get ("player");

    if (player !== undefined) {

        players.push (player);

        pausePlayer (player);
    }                
}

function playPlayer (player) {

    // this happends when player is not fully initialized yet
    if (typeof player.pauseVideo === "function") {

        player.playVideo ();

    } else {

        // if the player is not ready yet catch the event
        player.addEventListener ('onReady', function (event) { 

            player.playVideo (); 
        });
    }
}

function pausePlayer (player) {

    // this happends when player is not fully initialized yet
    if (typeof player.pauseVideo === "function") {

        player.pauseVideo ();

    } else {

        // if the player is not ready yet catch the event
        player.addEventListener ('onReady', function (event) { 

            player.pauseVideo (); 
        });
    }
}

function isInViewport (element, edge) {

    var h = window.innerHeight;                 // viewport height
    var r = element.getBoundingClientRect ();   // elements bounding rect in viewport coordinates

    // console.log ("top    : " + r.top);
    // console.log ("bottom : " + r.bottom);
    // console.log ("height : " + h);

    // add extra margin to the viewport to ensure that 
    // big enough portion of the object is already visible

    var e = h * Math.min (edge, 0.4); // relative viewport factor, max 40%

    var top     = r.top     - e;
    var bottom  = r.bottom  - e;

    h = h - e*2;

    return (!((top > h) || (bottom < 0)));
}

window.onload = function(e){

    // console.log ("loaded");

    initPlayers (); // to catch the last one !

    // console.log ("players : " + players.length);

    function onScroll () {

        for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i ++) {

            var player      = players [i];                
            var iframe      = player.getIframe ();
            var container   = iframe.parentNode;

            if (isInViewport (container, 0.0)) {

                playPlayer  (player);   } else {
                pausePlayer (player);
            }
        }
    }

    // in the case object is already in the viewport
    onScroll ();

    window.addEventListener ("resize", onScroll);
    window.addEventListener ("scroll", onScroll);
}

</script>
```